# XAMARIN ANDROID APK BUILD ERROR

Tags: android, xamarin.android

This **error** keeps showing when I try to generate an **apk** file via visual studio:

Error       "aapt.exe" exited with code 1.
Error       The file "obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist

Answer (score 2):

I hope you found a solution but I will reply just in case anyone arrives to your question as I did.

Seems like there are number of reasons why this error can come up but the most common (also in my case) was a resource which had an invalid name. I found out the exact problem and which resource it was that was incorrectly named by enabling Detailed verbosity for MSBuild project build output. You can do that by going to

Visual Studio Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity

Set the verbosity to Detailed and Rebuild your android project. Then inspect the Output window and hopefully you will get closer to finding the problem.

Comment: Thanks, by me it was the activity name: <activity android:icon="@drawable/XX" android:label="XXX" android:name="MainActivity"> - Once I added the name it compiled correctly.